# How can I display all array data and not only the last results

Tags: php

I have the below array and I want to display the results below the date.

```
Array ( 
[2023_08_09] => 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Exercise] => Translate_09 [url] => georgeekpla1_create_sentenses ) 
[1] => Array ( [Exercise] => Translate_09 [url] => georgeekpla1_translate_sentenses ) ) 
[2023_08_08] => 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Exercise] => Translate [url] => georgeekpla1_translate_sentenses ) 
[1] => Array ( [Exercise] => Create [url] => georgeekpla1_create_sentenses ) ) 
)
```

I tried the below code but I get only the last results and NOT all results.

```
    for($x=0; $x<=count($combinedResults[$date][$x]);$x++){
        echo "<br>".$combinedResults[$date][$x]['Exercise'];
        echo "<br>".$combinedResults[$date][$x]['url'];
    }
```

How can I print all results from array per day?

Any idea?

Comment: What is `$date`?

Comment: You're not updating $date as far as we can see, so it can only ever output data for one of the dates in the outer array

Comment: $date is the date sotred in the SQL table.

Comment: Ok. But, as already mentioned, in the code you've provided you aren't altering it, so, if `$date` is set to `2023_08_08` then you'll only see the results from under that date, you won't see the results from under `2023_08_09`. Hence your problem. The answer below obviously resolves it by looping through all the possible date values within the array instead of relying on an external variable which isn't being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

```
foreach ($combinedResults as $date => $results) {
    echo "Date: $date<br>";
    
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo "Exercise: " . $result['Exercise'] . "<br>";
        echo "URL: " . $result['url'] . "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```